# ¿Tiene 'alguien' algo que ver con géneros gramaticales?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, género

Una persona me dijo que al usar la palabra 'alguien', ese alguien tiene que ser masculino. ¿Es cierto? Si lo es, ¿existe una palabra análoga para el género femenino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Alguien" es un pronombre indefinido que significa "alguna persona". Por tanto, puede designar a una persona de cualquier género. El §19.4o de la [Nueva gramática de la lengua española (NGLE)](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/buscar.cgi) dice:

> Cuando el contexto sintáctico deja claro que se está hablando de mujeres, es también frecuente la concordancia de *alguien* y *nadie* en masculino.

y pone como ejemplo, entre otros:

> Es poco probable que en el mes del amor y la amistad hubiera **alguien más regalado** que **ella** (*Tiempo* [Col.] 15/9/1996).

El §19.4ñ también dice que es posible concordar el pronombre *alguien* con un adjetivo femenino. Uno de los ejemplos que pone es:

> Esta mujer, de nombre Sorbst, era sabida, en efecto, como **alguien dotada** de una provocativa virilidad (Panero, *Lugar*).

pero esto es mucho menos común. En cualquiera de los dos casos, está claro que el pronombre *alguien* puede referirse a personas de cualquier género.

Comment: Si es poco común concordar 'alguien' con un adjetivo femenino, ¿de que otra manera se hablaría de alguien dotada?

Comment: No me queda claro la primera cotización: ¿Se refiere a cuando se está hablando exclusivamente de mujeres o se refiere a cuando se está hablando de personas en general?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy "Alguien dotado" es correcto para referirse a una persona de cualquier sexo, ya que el género gramatical masculino funciona como género por defecto. Si hay necesidad de hablar de una persona específicamente de un sexo u otro, hay que decir directamente "un hombre" o "una mujer".

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy cuando "alguien" habla solo de mujeres, se puede concordar adjetivo en masculino o en femenino. Cuando "alguien" habla de personas de género masculino o no especificado, se concuerda solo en masculino.

Comment: Aun estoy un poco confundido: ¿Es gramáticamente correcto decir "estoy enamorado de alguien llamada Maria" si soy bisexual (por lo cual el genero no esta especificado)?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy si escribes "alguien llamada María", estás especificando que María es una mujer. Si escribes "alguien llamado María", no estás especificando el género de María. En ninguno de los dos casos estás especificando tu propio género.

Comment: @wimi ¿Pero las dos frases son gramáticamente correctas, no?

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy sí.